# Dual booting 12.10 and Win 7 - boots directly to Win 7

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, boot-failure, bootloader

and thank you kindly for you help!

I'll preface this with saying that I realize this is a common problem, with lots of trouble-shooting guides available online; however, after multiple attempts with different guides, I've made zero progress and am hoping to someone could help me with my specific scenario.

First, my story:
-Initially, I installed Ubuntu 12.10 with the "Something Else" option with no problems. Used 4 GB Swap Logical Partition, 26 GB Primary Root Partition. Wanting to trying out Mint 13, I booted into Windows from GRUB2, used the latest version of EasyBCD (v2.2) to restore the Windows 7 bootloader to the MBR, deleted the Ubuntu partitions, reformatted them in NTFS. I then created a 30 GB partition of free space for Mint.

I installed Mint using the same partitioning described above for Ubuntu 12.10, using /dev/sda for the boot installation files, and everything seemed to go well, until I re-booted my computer and it went straight to Windows - I could find no way to get into Mint. So I went into windows, restored windows bootloader to the MBR w/ EasyBCD, deleted partitions, etc., as I figured I'd done enough messing around and would go with Ubuntu 12.10.

Now the problem:
I restarted my computer booting from the same Ubuntu USB key I originally used. Briefly, "error: "prefix" is not set" flashed on screen, and instead of being greeted with the GUI menu of "try vs. install Ubuntu", there was a menu with minimal graphics (like a BIOS menu) where I could select install, run from USB, etc. After selecting "Install Ubuntu", the familiar install wizard with a GUI came up, I partitioned my drive as described, /dev/sda for the boot installation files, install went well, rebooted and...straight to Windows. This is where I'm at.

Fixes I've tried:
-This guide:
[How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)
to ensure Grub is on the MBR. I followed all steps, but still when I reboot, I go directly into Windows.

-Installing 12.04 instead of 12.10 - same issue

-Re-installed Ubuntu, writing the boot files to their own partition, then using EasyBCD to to add a boot option for Ubuntu using the Windows bootloader, ensuring I instruct EasyBCD to look at the partition I created with the Ubuntu installer (instructions here http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/Ubuntu). When I reboot, I select the Ubuntu option, and it puts me in GRUB4DOS, with a cursor waiting for input. I have no idea what to put here, so I would just type "reboot" to exit out.

And this is where I am now. Any clue as to why I can't boot into Ubuntu?

My computer specs are:
ASUS UX31A
Core i7, Win 7 64 Pro, 256 GB SSD, Intel HM76 Chipset and Integrated Intel HD 4000 Graphics, 4 GB memory

I've tried to be as clear as possible, but I'd be happy to provide any info that would help anyone along. Thanks for your patience in reading this!

Sincerely,

-MN

Comment: Please add to your question how the disk is presently partitioned. Boot from liveUSB and in a terminal type `sudo fdisk -l`.

Comment: Please run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and indicate the URL it will display.

Comment: OK! Thanks LovinBuntu! I actually forgot to mention I tried Boot-Repair before to no avail, but re-tried it and it worked this time! In case you're curious, the URL Boot-Repair output was paste.ubuntu.com/1381109.

Answer (score 0):

When the booting process is taking place, press the `SHIFT` key and keep it pressed. Normally, a `GRUB` screen should pop up and you will choose your OS.